# adding array to Object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to loop through Json twice: once for parent elements and then again for more detail.  (This eventually will be exported to XML)  In the meantime, how do I go about adding an array to an Object?  My current code doesn't create XMLObjectDetail

```
 XMLObject = {};
 var XMLObjectDetail = [];

 $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        XMLObject.CardCode = element['CardCode'] 
        XMLObject.CardName = element['CardName'];
        console.log(XMLObject);

  $.each(element, function(key, value) { 
       XMLObject[[XMLObjectDetail.InvPayAmnt]] = value['InvPayAmnt']; 
      });
  });
```

Comment: Do you want to add the object to the array or the other way round?

Comment: I would like to add the array XMLObjectDetail to the object XMLObject.

Comment: Which property name should it get in the XMLObject?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After you clarified your request in the comments, the solution is easy:

```
var XMLObject = {};
var XMLObjectDetail = [];
XMLObject["XMLObjectDetail"] = XMLObjectDetail;
```

you may shorten it to

```
var XMLObjectDetail, XMLObject = {XMLObjectDetail: XMLObjectDetail = []};
```

However, I need to mention some serious flaws in your code:

```
XMLObject = {}; // no var keyword: the variable will be global
var XMLObjectDetail = [];

$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    // I don't know how your data object/array looks like, but your code will be 
    // executed many times
    // For each element, you will overwrite the properties
    XMLObject.CardCode = element['CardCode'] // missing semicolon
    XMLObject.CardName = element['CardName'];
    // so that the final XMLObject will only contain cardcode and -name of the last one
    // It will depend on your console whether you see different objects
    // or the same object reference all the time
    console.log(XMLObject);

    // This part is completey incomprehensible
    // you now loop over the properties of the current element, e.g. CardCode
    $.each(element, function(key, value) { 
        // and again you only overwrite the same property all the time
        XMLObject[[XMLObjectDetail.InvPayAmnt]] = value['InvPayAmnt'];
        // but wait: The property name you try to set is very, um, interesting.
        // first, XMLObjectDetail is still an (empty) Array and has 
        //  no 'InvPayAmnt' property - leads to a undefined
        // then, you build an Array with that [undefined] value as the only item
        // OMG, an array? JavaScript does only allow strings as property names,
        //  so the array will be converted to a string - resulting to the empty string ""
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my code. As you can tell I am new to working with Json. I'll give you a bit of a background.  This code is taking data from a csv (which is made up of an export from a db). It then has to display it to the user and allow him to make certain changes. Then, he clicks a button, and it gets converted to an XML. This is my clients requirements.

Comment: The reason I thought to do a loop twice is because when there are rows with the same vendor id, they need to be grouped together and I need to display the sum for certain values. As well as show each individual row (or invoice).  Can you recommend a better way to structure this?

Comment: So which part of your algorithm are these two loops? The XML serialisation? I think you should ask a new question, giving us some sample data (the serialized JSON, or the CSV and your toJSON-parser), what you actually try to achieve with the problematic piece of code and which errors you encounter.

Comment: I just modified my question here. I hope its clear.  I REALLY appreciate you taking the time to help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835584/creating-a-multidimensional-object-for-xml-export

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add objects for `XMLObject` to array `XMLObjectDetail` do like this:

```
var XMLObject, XMLObjectDetail = [];

 $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        XMLObject=new Object(); //or XMLObject = {};
        XMLObject.CardCode = element['CardCode'] 
        XMLObject.CardName = element['CardName'];
        console.log(XMLObject);

        XMLObjectDetail.push(XMLObject);//ADDED OBJECT TO ARRAY

      //DON'T KNOW WHAT ARE YOU TRYING TO DO HERE?
      $.each(element, function(key, value) { 
           XMLObjectDetail[[XMLObjectDetail.InvPayAmnt]] = value['InvPayAmnt']; 
      });
  });
```

Comment: Sorry there was an error that I correct.  I am trying to create an object with an array inside it.  XMLObject is the main object and XMLObjectDetail is the array to which I'm assigning values in the second loop.  XMLObjectDetail needs to be inside XMLObject.

Comment: what is your object graph? or how are your arrays structured? does `data` (in first `$.each` construct) contains multiple `element` objects? is `element` an object or an array (that is `data` is an array of `element` array?