# Structure CSV into Object/Arrays

Tags: php, json

I am using this code to import a basic CSV in which each row represents an invoice.  I would like these invoices grouped by one of the columns and ultimately do a json_encode to produce a json with a parent/child hierarchy.  How do I go about doing this?

CSV

```
 ID      CardCode    sum            amount     
 165     BENV5271    100            100 
 026     BENV5635    509.85         287.33
 9025    BENV5635    509.85         222.52
```

PHP

```
if (($handle = fopen('upload/BEN-new.csv', "r")) === FALSE) {
    die('Error opening file'); 
}
 $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
 $cardCodes = array();

 while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ",")) {
    $cardCodes[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
}
fclose($handle);
```

JSON (goal)

```
 [ {
 "CardCode":"BENV5271", 
 "payment_sum": "100.00"
 "details": [ {
    "DocNum": "165",
    "InvPayAmnt": "100.00",
    "PmntDate": "2012-03-29"
  } ],

}, {
 "CardCode": "BENV5635",
 "payment_sum": "509.85"
 "details": [ {
     "DocNum": "026"  
     "InvPayAmnt": "287.33",
     "PmntDate": "2012-03-29"
   }, {
     "DocNum": "025",
     "InvPayAmnt": "222.52",
     "PmntDate": "2012-03-29"
   } ],
} ]
```

Comment: you can use `json_encode($row)` php inbuild function

Comment: But that will not create the hierarchy..

Comment: SO isn't about having other people write your code for you.  If you want that, you need to contract someone and pay them.

Comment: @Crontab Clearly they're a noob at arrays and this is not a complex problem.

Comment: You should link to the previous question and its solution algorithm. Your last approach wasn't that bad. Take the $complete and try it with PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: I would like to use @Bergi 's JS solution but in PHP first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835584/creating-a-multidimensional-object-for-xml-export

Comment: For future reference, using `var_dump()` or `var_export()` is a very good way to visualise data and the results of you manipulating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `$row`,

```
@$cardCodes[$row[1]]['payment_sum'] += $row[3];
@$cardCodes[$row[1]]['details'][] = array(
    'DocNum' => $row[0],
    'InvPayAmnt' => $row[3],
    'PmntDate' => $row[4?],
);
```

Not exactly the same format but indexed, and good for `for x in y` loops in your js.

Comment: Don't you need to create the 'details' array first?

Comment: should this be inside the while loop? or should I write a new foreach loop to do this?

Comment: @Crontab This is a valid use of the error suppression operator as it only creates arrays that my not be uninitalised, and nulls where no value exists. No different from doing an isset first. For such a simple format translation, no harm is done.

Comment: @user1413248 Why would you loop through the data twice? Write to the array as you read it.

Comment: @Walf Whatever, it's lazy, that's all I'm getting at.  Do it your way.

Comment: @Crontab You're confusing lazy with efficient. Also, I think it's good you wanted to offer a different approach but, next time, add another solution and reference the one it's based on, like everyone else.